# WHat do i need to add, remove or replace to make this work?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header, exit

i keep getting a conflicting type error when i get try to compile my code

the function declaration was made in my header file and the function itself was created in another file

but yet i still keep getting a an error.

need help with this

[image: function made in separate file][image: declaration in header file]

i was expecting compilation success

Comment: **Never** post pictures of code. Take the time to create a properly formatted, text, [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Remove This Error, Rename `_exit()` Method To Something Else,
Since another Method With Same Name Is Declared In The Libraries You Have Included In `main.h` file.
That's All You Just Need To Do.